# How to make ubuntu server auto shutdown after few hours

Tags: server, 20.04, power-management, shutdown, automation

I want to make my server auto ON and OFF. I turn ON server by BIOS option everyday at 8:00am. How can I make, that system will shutdown auto everyday at 11:59pm?

Answer (score 1):

Add a root cronjob:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Add:

```
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
# 
# m h  dom mon dow   command
59 23 * * * /sbin/shutdown -h now
```